# adding end points in prometheus integration

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

How to add/integrate rest api end points in `prometheus`. For eg in `splunk` we are monitoring micro services transactions and logs.

Lets say below spring boot:-

```
/abc/v1/something
/abce/v1/something2
```

In one line :-how can we add above micro services end points to `prometheus` for motioning

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit? I assume you have a bunch of Spring Boot (which version?) applications and you would like to expose metrics in these applications for being scraped by Prometheus directly?

Comment: hi @mweirauch . Currently we are having splunk for logs and alerts monitoring. Having micro services on spring Boot 2. Now we need to implement the monitoring of particular api's trasnactions (for e.g response time, latency) in grafana and prometheus as datasource.  so looking for how we can add data points in prometheus or how to pull data in prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot 2, you can easily expose your application metrics for Prometheus. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-export-prometheus). You'd add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and the Prometheus support with `micrometer-registry-prometheus` to your dependencies.

This will expose the metrics under `/actuator/prometheus` in the Prometheus exposition format to be scraped by your Prometheus instance.

Assumung you are using Spring WebMvc, then you'll get out-of-the-box metrics for your HTTP endpoints. (Jersey support is also provided with an extra module/dependency.)